# IF Statements After CTE's

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

Today I encountered this weird problem to do with IF statements. After I was done replacing/creating CTE's, I had IF statements after my CTE's and kept getting the following error:

> Incorrect Syntax near 'if'

Query:

```sql
-- Other CTE's above.
CTE6 AS 
(
    SELECT
        -- Multiple Columns
    FROM
        table1
)
-- When the Query runs, I'd like it to use the correct IF BLOCK.

-- Error starts here.
if @param_policy = '1' 
    select * from CTE4
    where mid not in (select distinct mid from CTE6)
        and [CN] = @param_policy

if @param_policy = '2' 
    select * from CTE4 
    where mid not in (select distinct mid from CTE6)
        and [CN] = @param_policy

if @param_policy = '3' 
    select * from CTE4 
    where mid not in (select distinct mid from CTE6)
        and [CN] = @param_policy                

if @param_policy = '4' 
    select * from CTE4 
    where mid not in (select distinct mid from CTE6)
        and [CN] = @param_policy   
-- UPDATED

select * from CTE4 WHERE @param_policy = 'batch' and mid not in (select distinct mid from CTE6)

and not
(([Client Number] ='5' and  Pnum = 'IN' )
or ([Client Number] ='6' and  Pnum = 'G')
or [Client Number] in ('7' , '8', '9')
)
```

Also to include, when it's doing `select * from CTE4` it is considering CTE4 to be invalid and also, it is not recognizing 'mid' to be a valid column.

My CTE's were temp tables before.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: You 4 SQLs look exactly the same. If that is the case, why do you need the `if`? If that's not the case, you might get better answers if you show us how the cases actually differ.

Comment: Unfortunately, your idea of replacing temp tables with CTEs requires that you redesign your code. Simply put, CTEs can be referenced by a single statement only. Perhaps you should go back to using temp tables - making suggestions based on incomplete code and unknown goals can be misleading.

Comment: @SMor OPENQUERY does not allow temptables so had to switch to CTE's. This was the only suggested way to "redesign" my query.

Comment: `OPENQUERY` is used in the `FROM` clause, and as such, is not going to work with `IF` statements. A better approach would be to fetch all the data from the `OPENQUERY` and then filter locally. If you truly need to execute conditional statements on the remote server, look into using `EXEC AT`.

Comment: This is an example of the XY Problem. http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Aside: Since you have Classified DDL that you cannot share with us, we are left pondering whether `[Client Number]` is really a string or you just like to compare it to strings like `'6'`.

Comment: Compare it to strings like. @HABO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
select *
from CTE4
where @param_policy in ('1', '2', '3', '4')  and
      mid not in (select distinct mid from CTE6) and
      [CN] = @param_policy;
```

`IF` is control flow for T-SQL code.  It is not part of `SELECT` query syntax.

More generally, you can do what you want with `union all`:

```
select *
from CTE4
where @param_policy in ('1', '2', '3', '4')  and
      mid not in (select distinct mid from CTE6) and
      [CN] = @param_policy
union all
select *
from CTE4 
where @param_policy = 'batch' and
      mid not in (select distinct mid from CTE6) and
      not (([Client Number] ='5' and  Pnum = 'IN' ) or
           ([Client Number] ='6' and  Pnum = 'G') or
           ([Client Number] in ('7' , '8', '9')
          );
```

You could also add these conditions to a single query, but I think the `union all` is the more general approach that you are looking for.

EDIT:

Or, just using more complex logic in the `WHERE`:

```
select *
from CTE4
where mid not in (select distinct mid from CTE6) and
      ( (@param_policy in ('1', '2', '3', '4')  and
         [CN] = @param_policy
         ) or
         (@param_policy = 'batch' and
          not (([Client Number] ='5' and  Pnum = 'IN' ) or
               ([Client Number] ='6' and  Pnum = 'G') or
               ([Client Number] in ('7' , '8', '9')
              )
         )
      )
```

Comment: Hey Gordon, quick question. What would be another approach instead of using 'union all'? I'm not quite sure whether or not that'll affect query run time. Any other recommendations? @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @LifeOfJona . . . With base tables, `union all` often gives more opportunities for optimizing the query (not always, but sometimes).  With CTEs, the CTE will be evaluated for each reference and that might tip the balance back to using `or` in a `where` clause.